# How to get the Timezone Hour and Minute in Java?

Tags: java, timezone

I found a code on how to get a Timezone:
    TimeZone.getDefault().getID()
It returns the name or Timezone region like "Asia/Singapore" or "Asia/Manila".
Is there anyone who knew how to get the sign, timezone hour, and timezone minute?
like +08:00, or -09:30
Thanks!

Comment: Please read "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), and notice that in the accepted answer, you are getting the *current* offset - which may or not be the offset applicable to the date/time you are working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern "Z" in SimpleDateFormat is close to what you want:

```
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("Z");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Output:

```
-0400
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() / 3600000
```

(3600000 is 60 seconds x 60 minutes x 1000 milliseconds)